# PHP: Getting the email from a form and sending it when a button is clicked

Tags: php, forms, email, button, send

So I want the site to send 2 emails - to the staff and to the client. The staff has a preset email, while the client has to write it inside a text box (form). I tried to get the client's mail.

```
<form id='contact-info' method='post' novalidate class="form contact-info">
    <div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-mail">
        <input type='email' name='user-mail' placeholder='Your email' class="form__mail">
    </div>
    <div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-tel">
        <input type='tel' name='user-tel' placeholder='Phone number' class="form__mail">
    </div>
</form>


</div>

<div class="order">
    <a href="Rezervare-final.html" name="button1" class="btn btn-md btn--warning btn--wide">Cumpara</a>
</div>

And here's the php right after the html.

<?php
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
    $toclient = "Test client";
    $tostaff = "Test staff";
    $maile = $_POST['user-mail'];
    $toclient = wordwrap($toclient, 70);
    $tostaff = wordwrap($tostaff, 70);
    mail($maile, 'My Subject', $toclient);
    mail('example@yahoo.com', 'My Subject', $tostaff);
}
?>
```

I am able to receive the staff email, but not the client email. Question: why can't I receive the client email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using submit button to submit data so you can't get the `$_POST['user-mail']` value.

if you use code something like,it should work

```
<form id='contact-info' method='post' class="form contact-info" action="" >
                <div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-mail">
                    <input type='email' name='user-mail' placeholder='Your email' class="form__mail">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-tel">
                    <input type='tel' name='user-tel' placeholder='Phone number' class="form__mail">
                </div>
                          <input type='submit' name='button1' value="submit">
            </form>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some javascript in the mix that you're not sharing with us that form would never submit; the button1 is a link to Rezervare-final.html

So, you need to replace the link with a **submit button** :

```
<input value= "Cumpara" type = "submit"/>
```

or

```
<button type="submit">Cumpara</button>
```

In your processing script don't listen for the button; listen for the email field if thats the only mandatory field:

```
if(isset($_POST['user-mail'])){

//process form/emails
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.....file name should be Rezervare-final.php not Rezervare-final.html**

```
<form id='contact-info' method='post' action="Rezervare-final.php" class="form contact-info">
    <div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-mail">
        <input type='email' name='user-mail' placeholder='Your email' class="form__mail">
    </div>
    <div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-tel">
        <input type='tel' name='user-tel' placeholder='Phone number' class="form__mail">
    </div>
</form>


</div>

<div class="order">
    <input type='submit' name='button1' value="Cumpara" class="btn btn-md btn--warning btn--wide>
</div>

And here's the php right after the html.

<?php
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
    $toclient = "Test client";
    $tostaff = "Test staff";
    $maile = $_POST['user-mail'];
    $toclient = wordwrap($toclient, 70);
    $tostaff = wordwrap($tostaff, 70);
    mail($maile, 'My Subject', $toclient);
    mail('example@yahoo.com', 'My Subject', $tostaff);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='contact-info' method='post' novalidate class="form contact-info">
<div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-mail">
    <input type='email' name='user-mail' placeholder='Your email' class="form__mail">
</div>
<div class="contact-info__field contact-info__field-tel">
    <input type='tel' name='user-tel' placeholder='Phone number' class="form__mail">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
</div>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$toclient = "Test client";
$tostaff = "Test staff";
$maile = $_POST['user-mail'];
$toclient = wordwrap($toclient, 70);
$tostaff = wordwrap($tostaff, 70);
mail($maile, 'My Subject', $toclient);
mail('example@yahoo.com', 'My Subject', $tostaff);
}
?>
```

Try this and i do belive you are missing some headers in your php script aswell see php manual hope it works :)